# CMake creates lots of targets I didn't specify

Tags: cmake

I am still learning CMake and am using it in a small project with a library and a test (using Catch2). My setup is Windows 10, GCC 6.3.0 with MinGW, CMake 3.13.3 and VSCode with CMakeTools plugin. Project structure:

```
.
+- build
+- doc
+- src
|  +- CMakeLists.txt
|  +- /* .hpp and .cpp sources */
+- test
|  +- CMakeLists.txt
|  +- unit_tests.cpp
+- CMakeLists.txt
```

Now, the problem is that while everything works, I am getting a load of targets built apart from `src` and `test` targets:

```
ContinuousBuild.dir/
ContinuousTest.dir/
ExperimentalMemCheck.dir/
NightlyMemoryCheck.dir/
ContinuousConfigure.dir/
ContinuousUpdate.dir/
ExperimentalStart.dir/
Nightly.dir/
NightlyStart.dir/
ContinuousCoverage.dir/
Experimental.dir/
ExperimentalSubmit.dir/
NightlyBuild.dir/
NightlySubmit.dir/
ContinuousMemCheck.dir/
ExperimentalBuild.dir/
ExperimentalTest.dir/
NightlyConfigure.dir/
NightlyTest.dir/
ContinuousStart.dir/
ExperimentalConfigure.dir/
ExperimentalUpdate.dir/
NightlyCoverage.dir/
NightlyUpdate.dir/
Continuous.dir/
ContinuousSubmit.dir/
ExperimentalCoverage.dir/
NightlyMemCheck.dir/
```

They are located at `build/CMakeFiles/`. I don't know how to get rid of them?
Here's a dump of my 3 CMakeList.txt files:

```
####################################
# root
####################################

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)

project(TestProject CXX)

set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17 )
set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON )
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )

find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
include(Catch)
include(CTest)

add_subdirectory(test)
add_subdirectory(src)

enable_testing()

add_test( ${PROJECT_NAME}_test_all
    unit_tests
)
####################################
# ./source
####################################

add_library( my_lib
    A.hpp
    A.cpp
    B.hpp
    B.cpp
)

####################################
# ./test
####################################

add_executable(
    unit_tests
    unit_tests.cpp
)

target_include_directories( unit_tests
    PRIVATE ../src/
)

target_link_libraries( unit_tests
    my_lib
    Catch2::Catch2
)
```

As a side question, I had to use `set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )` or else the unit_tests.exe file was being put inside `build\test` and CMake couldn't find it to run the tests; is there a better way?

Comment: Feel free to point any improvements to project structure (I am already planning to put the "A" and "B" files into separate directories). The project is intended to be part of my portfolio as a medium-sized project.

Comment: These extra targets look like something generated by [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2), their Github may have some info for how to disable these. Did you try turning off the CMake option `CATCH_BUILD_EXTRA_TESTS`?

Comment: This seems to be normal when including CTest for CTest/CDash continuous build support.  If that isn't want you want then don't use it.  You might want to take a look at what the module does and just copy the appropriate pieces you need without CDash support.  Also I stopped using CMakeTools for VSCode since it would cause two or more instances of cmake to run at the same time.  It was easier to just create my own build task to run `cmake --build workdir`.

Comment: @Fred actually, it was CTest, thanks. Answer the question and I will mark yours as correct, if you want. On a side note thanks for the tip, will strive to learn tasks.

Comment: It's normal for build tree to copy the same directory as the source tree.  So `build\test\unit_tests.exe` is the expected location.  You can either relocate the executable to a location that your command is expecting or to use a target property like `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` to get the location and use that in the test command instead.  But `add_test()` should find the proper location of an executable target if it was created by `add_executable()` according to it's documentation.  But if it is not working it belongs in another question (and the syntax you are using doesn't look correct).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be normal when including CTest for CTest/CDash continuous build support.

This module performs several actions including defining the `BUILD_TESTING` variable.  An important portion of this module is to call the command `enable_testing()`.

It then includes other modules that create extra files and some extra custom targets to support continuous build support.

Answer (score 7):

You can prevent those from being created by doing `set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY CTEST_TARGETS_ADDED 1)` anywhere in your CMake code, before calling `enable_testing()`.

Code that adds those is in [CTestTargets.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.16.2/Modules/CTestTargets.cmake#L49)

Comment: This does work, however I only managed to get it to work by including the `set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY CTEST_TARGETS_ADDED 1)` before the `include(CTest)`.